# Getting unknown error when launching large kernel sizes

Tags: c++, cuda

I am running into a problem when launching a simple kernel when my array size becomes larger than 591 by 591. At a size of 591x591 the array is returned without any error, but as soon as I launch the kernel with grid dimensions of 38x38 blocks with 16x16 threads each, the kernel fails to launch and returns an "unknown error".

The following code is the kernel I am calling and the call to the kernel in my code:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_device_runtime_api.h>

using namespace std;

#define BLOCKSIZE 16
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__,__LINE__);}

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
if (code != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    if(abort) exit(code);
}
}



__global__ void IdentityMatrixKernel(float* identity, int size)
{
int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

// map the two 2D indices to a single linear, 1D index
int grid_width = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
int index = index_y * grid_width + index_x;

// map the two 2D block indices to a single linear, 1D block index
//int result = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;


if (index % (size+1))
{
    identity[index] = 0;
}
else
{
    identity[index] = 1;
}


void foo(float *aArray, int size)
{
float* d_I;
int size2 = size*size*sizeof(float);

gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_I,size2));

dim3 block_size;
block_size.x = BLOCKSIZE;
block_size.y = BLOCKSIZE;

dim3 grid_size;
grid_size.x = size1/ block_size.x + 1;
grid_size.y = size1/ block_size.y + 1;

IdentityMatrixKernel<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(d_I,size);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(aArray,d_I,size2,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

cudaFree(d_I);
}

int main()
{
int size = 591;
float *aArray = (float*)malloc(size*size*sizeof(float));

foo(aArray,size);


return 0;
}
```

For `size = 591` no error shows up, outputs identity matrix of size 591x591 but for any larger size it spits out an "unknown error" to console.

Comment: I guess this is not the code you are running.  There are various compile issues.  Please check to make sure the code you post will actually compile, and sort out any issues, and then make sure it actually demonstrates the issue.  Then run your code with `cuda-memcheck` and I think you'll see that your kernel is generating a lot of errors (e.g. out of bounds accesses - invalid global writes of size 4, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem seems to be that you are launching a grid of threads that is larger than your actual matrix:

```
grid_size.x = size1/ block_size.x + 1;
grid_size.y = size1/ block_size.y + 1;
```

But you are not checking for any out-of-bounds accesses in your kernel.  You need to add a thread check such as:

```
if ((index_x >= size)||(index_y >= size)) return;
```

near the beginning of your kernel.  But that's not enough.  Another problem is that your `index` calculation is not correct:

```
int index = index_y * grid_width + index_x;
```

On the surface of it, it appears to be correct, but since your thread array is larger than your data array (potentially), this can give incorrect indexing.  Since you're passing `size` to the kernel anyway, change it to something like this:

```
int index = index_y * size + index_x;
```

And you should be able to eliminate the out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes, I changed the way I was indexing and then removed the "+1" from the grid_size calculation and its all working.

Answer (score 0):

I extend Robert Crovella's answer.

If you define block_size.{x, y} with a big number (in your case 16), then you won't be able to work with arrays of smaller size e.g. 4x4. What you could do is define a small block size:

```
/* create thread blocks */
dim3 block_size;
block_size.x = 4;
block_size.y = 4;

/* create n x n block grids */
dim3 grid_size;
grid_size.x = size1/block_size.x;
grid_size.y = size1/block_size.y;

/* in case of partial sizes make grid_size 1 x 1 */
if (size1 % block_size.x)
    grid_size.x = 1, grid_size.y = 1;
```

Comment: Thread blocks of 16 threads is usually a poor choice. The thread check I mention can be used to handle small arrays.

Comment: Sorry to post as an answer but cannot comment yet. I only meant to advice him/her before he/she find the next problem/obstacle. It's crucial to understand for which geometry the solution works on the GPU and probably user3390212 haven't thought of that seeing from the errors he had in his code.